# How to pass ArrayList of different types to method?

Tags: java, types, arraylist

I want to define a method -

```
public static void summary1(ArrayList<Type> a){
    //some code        
}
```

I want to have the flexibility of replacing "Type" with any thing (Integer, Double, Long, etc). Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally mean "anything", and you don't need access to the type within the method:

```
public static void summary1(List<?> list){
}
```

If you need access to the type:

```
public static <T> void summary1(List<T> list){
    // type T is available to code in here
}
```

All your examples were `Number` classes, so if you want to restrict it to those:

```
public static <T extends Number> void summary1(List<T> list){
   // a list of Numbers
}
```

and if you also need the `Comparable` behaviour that all `Number` classes have (but `Number` alone does not):

```
public static <T extends Number & Comparable<T>> void summary1(List<T> list){
   // a list of Numbers, and you can compare them
}
```

Note also that I have changed the type to the abstract type `List`, instead of the implementation `ArrayList` - see [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)

Answer (score 4):

```
public static <T> void summary1(ArrayList<T> list){
   //now you can pass any list here
}
```

If you want to use `T` in some way.

or you can use wildcard operator `?` if you don't care what type of `List` is being passed to `summary1`

References:
 - [Generics and wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `<?>` notation as

```
public static void summary1(ArrayList<?> a){
    //some code        
}
```

Also, if you want to restrict to subtypes of `Number`, you can add

```
public static void summary1(ArrayList<? extends Number> a){
    //some code        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use the wildcard `?`. So `ArrayList<?>` would mean an ArrayList of anything. By what you wrote, I assume you just want numbers, so you can do something like `ArrayList<? extends Number>` so that you can only pass ArrayLists of classes that extend Number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Java expert, but from what I know, you will need to explicitly create methods for each type you expect to see. For example:

```
public static void summary1(ArrayList<String> a){
    //some code        
}

public static void summary1(ArrayList<Integer> a){
    //some code        
}

public static void summary1(ArrayList<Double> a){
    //some code        
}

etc...
```

Then as your method is called, the correct method will be invoked based on the type that is passed to it.

Comment: You should *try* this code .. Java generics are effectively erased during compilation, so *all* the methods above are effectively `static void summary1(ArrayList a)`, which is problematic for overloading.

Comment: I'll spare you a down vote because of your disclaimer but the JLS considers this a compile time error. Two methods with the same name can't have the same erasure. In the source code basically this would just look like 3 identical methods.